# Are $A|B$ and $B$ independent events?

Tags: conditional-probability, machine-learning, independence

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two dependent events, that is $P(A\cap B)>0$. We know that $P(A\cap B)=P(A|B)P(B)$. Is it true that $A|B$ and $B$ are independent?

From my understanding, two events $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if $P(X\cap Y)=P(X)P(Y)$. It seems to me that $A|B \cap B = A\cap B$, so the joint probability of $A|B$ and $B$ should also be $A\cap B$. Then, they should be independent? Is my intuition correct?

Now, in the context of machine learning, suppose $A$ and $B$ denote distribution of two features for the model. Then, I can empirically calculate $A|B$ from the data. Then if I transform my feature vectors from $(A, B)$ to $(A|B, B)$, they should be independent. Is it actually done in practice?

**Edit:** Corrected a mistake in phrasing of the question as pointed out in the first answer. (Thanks!) My question is yet to be answered.

Comment: How exactly do you plan to "compute $A|B$"? What kind of thing do you think $A|B$ is?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. To my understanding, $A|B$ is an event. Given a dataset, I was planning to compute something like $P(A=a|B=b)=\frac{\text{total occurrences with $A=a$ and $B=b$}}{\text{total occurrences of $B=b$}}$. I have tried with bivariate normal distribution with mean 0 and covariance matrix $[[4, 3], [3, 4]]$. It seems like setting a threshold for double comparison at around $0.0001$ reduces the correlation between $A|B$, $B$ pretty close to zero. (I understand that 0 correlation does not imply independence, was just a quick check.) :)

Comment: $A\mid B$ is not an event. Here $A\mid B$ does **not** denote the set-theoretic difference of $A$ and $B$. Indeed, $A\mid B$ has no meaning by itself, it is just a substring of $P(A\mid B)$, which denotes the conditional probability of $A$ conditional on $B$.

Answer (score 2):

No. $P(A|B)$ and $P(B)$ are numbers, not events.